# Decreasing Number staircase in python 2.7

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, nested-loops

I am fairly new to array data structures. I am trying to print the below pattern in python.

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Here is my code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
n = len(a)
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
        print a[j],
```

Output: I am getting the correct order. I just can't seem to arrange the answer in the desired format. Any suggestions?

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

Comment: Add `print` after inner loop to print new lines.

Comment: While not a duplicate question, this may be useful to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Comment: @falsetru Tried that. can't seem to get it to work. can you please provide a more elaborate explanation?

Comment: https://ideone.com/TQLIrb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really just interested in learning about list manipulations, and don't need exactly the output you've shown, you might consider this approach, which makes use of basic list indexing:

```
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(a[:i])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1]
```

Along those lines, you can get your specified output by converting the values in each row to type `str`, joining each row's characters, and then printing:

```
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(''.join(str(el) for el in a[:i]))
```

Output:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```